# Disable save button in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have Save button as part of `EditItemTemplate` of the grid. on click of the button I want to disable the button to have a single click disable effect.

1. I did try with javascript, in this case no server side code is executed.
2. Added the attribute to the button, even this doesn't help
3. Tried by adding `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` property too

What would be other possible solution to achieve this?

Comment: protected void gvw_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
                    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)e.Row.Cells[6].FindControl("btnSave");
                btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
            }
        }
            }

Comment: Is this the code or the required answer for your solution

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> **Here is the solution:**
>
> 1. Set the `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` for the button in `aspx` page.
> 2. In the `.c`s page, in the `RowDataBound` event write the following code:

```
///Grid row event RowDataBound
protected void gvr_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
       {
            ///Creating the Save button object
            Button btn = (Button)e.Row.Cells[6].FindControl("btnSave");

            ///Add the attribute to disblae the button
            btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
       }
   }
}
```